# Handle multiple actions with one button

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-listener

Button element calls popup menu including images, this works correctly. 
I have been trying to create a second event listener to change the style to `display:none` after the second click of the same button.
Every combination I try seems to either disable or cancel out the work I have already done.
I am new to Javascript and would greatly appreciate the help.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width;" />
<link href="scripts/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(n) {
        document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click", function({
            document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.display="block";}, false);
        }
</script>

</head>

<div align="center"><IMG SRC="images/m.index.png" WIDTH=640 HEIGHT=125></div>
<div align="center "id="menubutton"><img src="images/m.icon1.png">Main Menu</div>
<div id="mainmenu" style="display:none">
    <div class="row1">
        <a href='m.page1.html'><IMG SRC="images/m.icon2.png">Sub Menu 1</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row2">
        <a href='m.page2.html'><IMG SRC="images/m.icon3.png">Sub Menu 2</a>
    </div> 
    <div class="row3">
        <a href='m.page3.html'><IMG SRC="images/m.icon4.png">Sub Menu 3</a>
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a second listener. Just use the one you have to check, if the menu is visible or not:

```
document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click", function()
    {
        menu = document.getElementById("mainmenu");
        if (menu.style.display == "none") {
            document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.display="block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mainmenu").style.display="none";
        }
    }, false);
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3TR7r/).

You could also use jquery, which makes live a bit easier. Then you would have:

```
$('#mainmenu').click(function() { $('#mainmenu').toggle() });
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jens. After 18 hours trying to figure it out myself, you helped me get it working in a few minutes. At least I learnt a lot in the process. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

your talking about a toggle function in your case

```
var toggle=function(){
 var menu=document.getElementById("mainmenu");
 menu.style.display=(menu.style.display=='none'?'block':'none');
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click",toggle,false);
}
```

as u can see no need to use jquery, and writing the function properly its also a 'one line' function. it's also much faster than jquery.
also the function suggested by jens calls 3 times getelementbyid...and it's missing var on the first getelementbyid

but i use the modern way.

```
//css
#mainmenu{
 transition:all 700ms ease;
 /*-webkit,-moz,-ms,-o*/
 opacity:0;
}
#mainmenu.show{
 opacity:1;
}

//js
var toggle=function(){
document.getElementById("mainmenu").classList.toggle('show');
}
window.onload=function(){
document.getElementById('menubutton').addEventListener("click",toggle,false);
}
```

in the second case i change the opacity so that it fades in and out with a easing function in 700milliseconds

why?

1.animation

2.easy to change the animation function in the css without touching the js code (opacity,height,transform... whatever)

3.works on all modern browsers

4.display none slows down the browser as it renders the menu everytime.

a better approach using the 1st case is to use height:0px;overflow:hidden; or margin-top:-999999px; in the css as it just hides or moves it around with no need to rerender the menu